# How to match last line of text file in treeview and display text boxes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, treeview

I have a problem with a sorted TreeView. I select the last line of a text file, then I extract from this text file the last child node added in the TreeView. Where the shoe pinch is that I can't do it! I have tried with the number of lines in this file, but no results. In fact, I do a bit of everything (not of course) to get the selected node to coincide in the treeview and the displays in the text boxes. Below is a screenshot and my code! I don't know if I made myself understood correctly, my English is translated English. Thank you. Claude.

```
Dim NbLine As Integer = 0
        Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(OuvrirFichier)
        While Not SR.EndOfStream
            SR.ReadLine()
            NbLine += 1
        End While
        SR.Close()

        Dim lastLine As String = File.ReadLines(OuvrirFichier, Encoding.UTF8) _
                                .Where(Function(f As String) (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))).Last.ToString

        Dim mytext As String = lastLine.Substring(17, 90)

        If NbLine > 0 Then
            Dim lignesDuFichier As String() = File.ReadAllLines(OuvrirFichier, Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim derniereLigne As String = lignesDuFichier(lignesDuFichier.Length - 1)
            TreeView1.Focus()
            TreeView1.SelectedNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(lignesDuFichier.Length - 1)
        End If
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach seems a little off to me.  Might find the how thing a little easier to read the file only once into a collection which will allow you to present the data and keep everything together a little nicer in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in line.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OuvrirFichier = "C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\Code\Test Empty Line.txt" '"path to file"
    'At least you will only be reading the file once
    Dim AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(OuvrirFichier)
    Dim LinesWithContent = AllLines.Where(Function(s) s.Trim() <> String.Empty)
    Dim lastLine = LinesWithContent.Last
    Dim mytext As String = lastLine.Substring(17, 90)
    Debug.Print(mytext) 'Just checking that you get what was expected
    Dim NbLine = AllLines.Length
    Dim derniereLigne As String = AllLines(NbLine - 1) 'Another variable to hold last line??? 
    'But this time it could be a blank line.
    TreeView1.Focus()
    'This makes no sense. An index of a subNode base on the number of lines in the text file
    'is supposed to be the SelectedNode
    'Why would this be the last node added?
    TreeView1.SelectedNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(NbLine - 1)
    'You never test the equality of the SelectedNode with mytext
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Mary: it is indeed the last node added because it is the one which is displayed in the program. This is undoubtedly due to the fact that sorting is very troublesome under these conditions. Thank you very much Mary. I just tested it but it doesn't change the result. The focus is always on the last sorting item in the treeview!